# Jquery each and split issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, each

I've this code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/opencart/preventivo.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        var opzione=$("#tutte_le_macro_opzioni").text().split(" ");
        $.each(opzione, function( key, value ) {
            $(document).on("change","."+value,function () {
                //does something//
            });
        });
<div id="tutte_le_macro_opzioni"><?php echo "city,country,name"; ?></div>
```

Now the problem is that when I use `var opzione=$("#tutte_le_macro_opzioni").text().split(" ");` it gives to me this problem:

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
};
```

If I change `var opzione=$("#tutte_le_macro_opzioni").text().split(" ");` with `var opzione="city,country,name"` the script works perfectly. It seems a problem with split after a php result.

Could some one help me please?

UPDATE

this is the php code from I populate div tutte_le_macro_opzioni

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");  
$a="";
$query= "SELECT * FROM oc_option_description";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    

$a.=strtolower($row["name"]).",";   
}
echo $a;
?>
```

SOLVED

I replace the php code with this

ALL th code in one line...it seems case sensitive :-)

Comment: You're missing a `document.ready` handler, meaning `$("#tutte_le_macro_opzioni")` is empty, and you're iterating over something completely different than what you think, so `"."+value` is not a jQuery selector, and Sizzle throws an error. You could have figured this out in 10 seconds by just doing `console.log(opzione)` yourself too see what you've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace this :

```
var opzione=$("#tutte_le_macro_opzioni").text().split(" ");
$.each(opzione, function( key, value ) {
$(document).on("change","."+value,function () {

//does something//
});
});
```

By this :

```
$(function(){
  var opzione=$("#tutte_le_macro_opzioni").text().split(',');
  $.each(opzione, function( key, value ) {
    $(document).on("change","."+value,function () {

    //does something//
    });
  });
});
```

Since `$("#tutte_le_macro_opzioni").text()` contains the same as this "city,country,name" and it's a string, you have to split on ',' to get an array for `$.each()` loop.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71z6Lzb6/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but doesn't work in my case..I posted the php code from I get the value of tutte_le_macro_opzioni

Comment: ops sorry it returns this value "city,country,name,"  but I don't know why in this way it doesn't work

Comment: Very strange .. Can we see your page somewhere ? Did you include Sizzle js plugin ? Because the error is refering to it.

Comment: no...i don't know what's Sizzle...but I use only jquery validation and tinymce...I delete them and the result is the same. My page is now on localhost...:-(

Comment: can you copy all your code (php included) so we can have a global view of it please ?

Comment: Yeah but PHP code won't work in JSFiddle :/
Did you try to adapt your JS code with mine ?